# z-index for jQuery date picker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using jQuery date picker with buttonImage and below that there is a custom styled select form element (http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/ ) which uses z-index of 5.

I could not select the dates in datepicker in the portions where it overlaps with select box. In the css I have mentioned the z-index for datepicker as below:

.ui-widget { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; z-index:1000; }
.ui-datepicker, .ui-datepicker table, .ui-datepicker td, .ui-datepicker td span, .ui-datepicker td a {z-index:1000; }
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {z-index:1000; }

But still not working.  Any help?

Comment: Can you either post your html/css/javascript code or use jsfiddle.net to show us?

Comment: I menioned !important near z-index and it solved the problem. .ui-datepicker, .ui-datepicker table, .ui-datepicker td, .ui-datepicker td span, .ui-datepicker td a {z-index:1000 !important; }

Answer (score 0):

if you want the datepicker above your other css try this one:

```
<style>
    .ui-datepicker { z-index: 9999; }
</style>
```